# javacv code not running

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, javacv

I have been trying this for a long time. I have installed all the prerequisites.
1. Installed java jdk first
2. Installed Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable package 
3. Downloaded opencv package
4. Set OpenCV .dll in systems path.
5. Downloaded JavaCV- bin from link below and extract it.
6. Finally added all external JAR files to the eclipse Libraries.

Below is the demo code which I'm using for testing `javacv`

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.CanvasFrame;

public class demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     //Load image img1 as IplImage
        final IplImage image = cvLoadImage("backimg.png");

        //create canvas frame named 'Demo'
        final CanvasFrame canvas = new CanvasFrame("Demo");

        //Show image in canvas frame
        canvas.showImage(image);

        //This will close canvas frame on exit
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
    }    
}
```

Now when I run the project as a Java Application the following dialog box appears (included in the link below) :-

[Dialog box that appears in eclipse](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-MMvJ6Gd3K_0/UQNexUTRtDI/AAAAAAAAAEQ/XX_lPlJHs8s/s606/error.jpg)

Now I've tried all the options shown in the dialog box but the code is not running. It would be a great help if anyone could tell me what option should I select in the dialog box and the correct procedure for running the code if I'm wrong somewhere.

Comment: select 'demo - (default package)' from the list. Eclipse is asking you to select from the classes which contain `main` method.

Answer (score 1):

select 'demo - (default package)' from the list. Eclipse is asking you to select from the classes which contain main method.

Comment: thanks @Usman Saleem for your help but when I selected the option **demo - (default package)** from the list the following exception came :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\lokendra\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp620089620608\jniopencv_core.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Comment: there are more details to the exceptions but the whole text is not fitting here in Comments please do visit the link below for the detailed exception http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=5rbVu9aU

Comment: The error suggests that your program is unable to load the required dll. Double check the instructions of the framework you are trying to use (i.e. javacv).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError" can occur due to a mismatch in the version of JavaCV jars and required OpenCV libraries.
You can check the required version of OpenCV in the Readme file of javacv-bin